# Using CrmServiceClient to connect to CRM2013 org, "Unable to login to Dynamics CRM" using AuthType=IFD

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to use CrmServiceClient to connect to a CRM2013 org with a connection string 
"AuthType=IFD;Url=https://server.company.com/OrgName;Domain=DomainName;Username=DomainName\UserName;Password=UserPassword"
This works on some servers and not others

The error being returned is: "Unable to login to Dynamics CRM"
Is there anywhere I can look to get more details on the error? a log file somewhere?

The username & password are correct
using this connection string in XRMToolbox works

Any ideas on where to look would be greatly appreciated

I have also tried this connection string
"AuthType=IFD;Url=https://orgname.company.com/OrgName;Domain=DomainName;Username=DomainName\UserName;Password=UserPassword"

```
        try
        {
            if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol != SecurityProtocolType.Tls12)
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            using (var service = new CrmServiceClient(crmConnectionString))
            {
                if (!service.IsReady)
                {
                    if (service.LastCrmException != null)
                        throw service.LastCrmException;

                    throw new InvalidOperationException(service.LastCrmError);
                }

                    :
                    :
                    :
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String error = "";
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                error = ex.InnerException.Message;
            }
            else
            {
                error = ex.Message;
            }
            throw new Exception("RetrieveConfiguration, failed to authenticate user: " + error);
        }
```

Comment: Try removing Domain from the username, or formatting as username@domain

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but we tried all that.

Comment: Can you provide details on which versions of CRM you are able to connect to vs unable?

Comment: they are all CRM 2013 same rollup version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the ADFS Server did not have TLS 1.2 enabled.
Once that was enabled and the server rebooted, it started working just fine

Thanks Zach for trying to help with this